# Error while editing a post using Laravel update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This is my html form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{action('BlogController@update',[$blog->id]) }}" method="post">
            <input name="method" type="hidden" value="patch"/>
            <div class="form-group">
            <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
```

Here is route:

```
Route::patch('blog/{id}','BlogController@update');
```

Controller :

```
public function update(Request $request,$id){
    $input = $request->all();
    $blog  =findOrFail($id);
    Blog::update($input);
    //var_dump($input);
    return back();
}
```

Can you please show me where is the issue?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Blog.findOrFail($id);  because you have just findOrFail($id)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you have write `$blog  = findOrFail($id);` to get blog which is not correct. You can do it using

`$blog  = Blog::findOrFail($id);`

Now you have the blog, you need to update the blog. So, the update code should be

`$blog->update($input);`

To make this update method works, you need to make the fields(the fields you are updating) fillable in `Blog` model.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong syntax. Do something like this to make it work:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    Blog::where('id', $id)->update($request->all());
    return back();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

give the name whatever you wish say **blog**:

```
Route::patch('blog/{id}','BlogController@update')->name('blog');
```

your HTML code

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{route('blog', $blog->id)}}" method="post">
```

hope this help you!!

Answer (score 0):

you have many syntax problems!
try it this way:

form:

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" 
        action="{{ route('blog.update', ['id' => $blog->id]) }}" 
           method="post">
           {{ csrf_field() }}
                <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch"/>
                <!-- other inputs -->
      </form>
```

Route:

```
 Route::any('blog/{id}','BlogController@update')->name('blog.update');
```

Controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
    $blog = Blog::findOrFail($id);
    $blog->update([
   'key' => 'value'
]);
 // never use $request->all() because of security issues!
    return back();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{route('blog.update',[$blog->id]) }}" method="post">
       {{csrf_field()}}
{{ method_field('PATCH') }}
```

Your Route Like This

Route::resource('blog', 'BlogController');

Your Controller

public function update(Request $request,$id){

```
$blog  =Blog::findOrFail($id);
$blog->database_fieldname1=$request->value1;
$blog->database_fieldname2=$request->value2;
$blog->database_fieldname3=$request->value3;
$blog->save();
return back();
```

}